# Gatsby dark mode toggle not working on homepage in Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I just integrated a light/dark mode toggle into my Gatsby site [here](https://jessewinton.com/). I based it off of [Josh Comeau's article](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/dark-mode/), and it works just fine in Chrome. However on the homepage when using Safari, when I click the toggle button the background color doesn't change unless I resize the window. Here is my `gatsby-ssr.js`:

```
import React from 'react';

import { THEME_COLORS } from 'utils/theme-colors';

import { LOCAL_STORAGE_THEME_KEY } from './src/contexts/ThemeContext';

const SetTheme = () => {
  let SetThemeScript = `
    (function() {
      function getInitialTheme() {
        const persistedColorPreference = window.localStorage.getItem('${LOCAL_STORAGE_THEME_KEY}');
        const hasPersistedPreference = typeof persistedColorPreference === 'string';
 
        if (hasPersistedPreference) {
            return persistedColorPreference;
        }
        
        const mql = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');
        const hasMediaQueryPreference = typeof mql.matches === 'boolean';
        
        if (hasMediaQueryPreference) {
            return mql.matches ? 'dark' : 'light';
        }
        return 'light';
      }

      const colorMode = getInitialTheme();
      const root = document.documentElement;
      root.style.setProperty(
        '--color-primary',
        colorMode === 'dark'
          ? '${THEME_COLORS.dark}'
          : '${THEME_COLORS.light}'
      );
      root.style.setProperty(
        '--color-secondary',
        colorMode === 'dark'
          ? '${THEME_COLORS.light}'
          : '${THEME_COLORS.dark}'
      );
      root.style.setProperty(
        '--color-accent',
        colorMode === 'dark'
          ? '${THEME_COLORS.accentLight}'
          : '${THEME_COLORS.accentDark}'
      );
      root.style.setProperty('--initial-color-mode', colorMode);
    })()`;
  return <script id="theme-hydration" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: SetThemeScript }} />;
};
export const onRenderBody = ({ setPreBodyComponents }) => {
  setPreBodyComponents(<SetTheme />);
};
```

and my `ThemeToggle` component:

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';

import { ThemeContext } from 'contexts/ThemeContext';
import { DarkModeSwitch } from 'react-toggle-dark-mode';
import { THEME_COLORS } from 'utils/theme-colors';

import s from './ThemeToggle.scss';

export const ThemeToggle = () => {
  const { theme, toggleTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);

  const toggleDarkMode = (checked: boolean) => {
    toggleTheme(checked ? 'dark' : 'light');
  };

  return (
    <div className={s.toggler}>
      <DarkModeSwitch
        checked={theme === 'dark'}
        onChange={toggleDarkMode}
        size={20}
        sunColor={THEME_COLORS.dark}
        moonColor={THEME_COLORS.light}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure you need the `gatsby-ssr.js` part ? - https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode/

Comment: My understanding of using `gatsby-ssr.js` is to eliminate the flicker that can come with a dark/light mode. This runs prior to loading the page.

Comment: ok, I've used on my site and haven't noticed it - https://github.com/imshuffling/davidrich.es/tree/master/src/components , look at header.js and themeChanger.js

Comment: David, you're absolutely right, migrated to `gatsby-plugin-dark-mode` and it seems like the flicker was only present in development. Much simpler to maintain. Still buggy in Safari however.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't appear that the `toggleTheme` property being destructured from the `ThemeContext` value triggers a re-render, but resizing your browser window does. [Josh handles this by providing a setter function with a side effect](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/dark-mode-minimal/blob/5d4d5612667d06f9350f4ba3eea187df8a8231ff/src/components/ThemeContext.js#L27-L46) (it manipulates the root styles directly):

```js
  const contextValue = React.useMemo(() => {
    function setColorMode(newValue) {
      const root = window.document.documentElement;

      localStorage.setItem(COLOR_MODE_KEY, newValue);

      Object.entries(COLORS).forEach(([name, colorByTheme]) => {
        const cssVarName = `--color-${name}`;

        root.style.setProperty(cssVarName, colorByTheme[newValue]);
      });

      rawSetColorMode(newValue);
    }

    return {
      colorMode,
      setColorMode,
    };
  }, [colorMode, rawSetColorMode]);
```

Comment: I integrated this, and it still looks like it doesn't trigger a re-render in Safari.

Comment: With this you shouldn't need a re-render since the browser is replacing the styles. Are you not using the CSS var directly in the styles you supply the browser, perhaps? There's also a chance that something about `root.style.setProperty` that doesn't work well in Safari.

Comment: I ended up switching to `gatsby-plugin-dark-mode` to make things a bit cleaner and move away from `root.style.setProperty` but it's still buggy in Safari. Super weird.